# Android dependancies configuration

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies

I am going through the Android app tutorial here:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

As part of what I am doing I added in the appcompat library as part of adding in the themes.  Not sure how I got to this point but when I try to run the app I get the error :

"The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library `'D:\eclipse-bundle\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'"`

The library DOES exist, just not at this location.  It is located at:

`D:\eclipse-bundle\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar`

There does not appear to be any way to edit this property.  How do you fix this problem?  what is causing it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you follow this step to add .jar files.

> In the new library project, **expand the libs/ folder, right-click
>   each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path**. For
>   example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the
>   android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to
>   the build path.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue so I CMD+Q'd Eclipse and re-opened it.... magically worked. I guess "turning it off an on again" works sometimes :D

Answer (score 0):

You can select your project on eclipse, then right-click...

A menu should appear, you can click on "properties".

A flying screen should appear, you can click on "Java Build Path"

Another flying screen should appear, you can click on the tab "Libraries"

This tab actually hold references to what is in the "libs" folder, and you can delete your old lib and insert your new lib (with the correct path) there.

---

Would not recommend any of it, actually... Please just import the "support lib project" into your eclipse workspace and make your project reference the imported project as a "lib project".

That is way more handy, and will actually give you a better flexibility for doing more stuff with compatibility lib.

And also, since it is on your workspace, you are the one that compiles it. No future lib reference problems \o/

Comment: I don't think any of this applies.  On the screen you mention I see a red "x" on 'Android Dependencies' entry.  This is what is causing the error in question.  When I click the white arrow beside dependencies (I would post a pic but the site won't let me until I have more points on this site or whatever) I see the following line:

android-support-v7-appcompat.jar 'D:\eclipse-bundle\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar' (missing)

This is what is causing me the issue.  The 'edit' button is grayed out so I cannot change the path it is looking for this at.

Comment: If I delete 'Android Depenencies' and re-add it using Android tools -> Fix Project Properties it add back the same thing with the same property.

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas on how to fix this?  I believe the entry in Android Dependencies is there because I DID import the external project it references.  Is there anywhere else I can go to get information on how to configure eclipse to build for Android projects?

Comment: You actually should delete it from the entry and re-add it by copying your lib project to the "libs" folder (via ctrl+c, ctrl+z normally), instead of using  Android tools -> Fix Project Properties. There is a more or less well documented guide here also -> http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html
Hope it helps! Comment more if i can help